# How to fetch data from a stored procedure that has a cursor

Tags: mysql

I have got this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cursor_example//

CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_example()
BEGIN
    DECLARE niche_id INT;
    DECLARE niche_name VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM `niche`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN curl;
    my_loop:LOOP
        FETCH curl INTO niche_id, niche_name;
        IF done=1 THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP my_loop;
    CLOSE curl;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The question is, how do I take the niche id and niche_name rows out of the cursor after the cursor finished iterating. I cant get a result set from the stored procedure as a variable, cant I? So is the use of cursors for stored procedures is mainly for internal purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is - *'scalar values'*, then you can use one of this variants:

1. Run `SELECT niche_id, niche_name;` from the procedure.
2. Use OUT paremeters.

If the result is a set of values, then you should populate another table, e.g. temporary table.

Also, if you want to read some data from the table and store it into another table, then try to use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement instead of opening cursor.

Comment: But that doesnt make sense, the function doesnt terminate until the loop finishes..so all the variables are being fetched into two variables.. and i cant get those two variables without them being overwritten in the next loop iteration